# EMV RSA Recovery Function in c#

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, emv

I'm implementing the EMV issuer public key recovery in .net8.0 but cannot get this unit test to pass

```
// from javaemvreader
    var modulus = Convert.FromHexString("be9e1fa5e9a803852999c4ab432db28600dcd9dab76dfaaa47355a0fe37b1508ac6bf38860d3c6c2e5b12a3caaf2a7005a7241ebaa7771112c74cf9a0634652fbca0e5980c54a64761ea101a114e0f0b5572add57d010b7c9c887e104ca4ee1272da66d997b9a90b5a6d624ab6c57e73c8f919000eb5f684898ef8c3dbefb330c62660bed88ea78e909aff05f6da627b");
    var data = Convert.FromHexString("8b3901f6253048a8b2cb08974a4245d90e1f0c4a2a69bca469615a71db21ee7b3aa94200cfaedcd6f0a7d9ad0bf79213b6a418d7a49d234e5c9715c9140d87940f2e04d6971f4a204c927a455d4f8fc0d6402a79a1ce05aa3a526867329853f5ac2feb3c6f59ff6c453a7245e39d73451461725795ed73097099963b82ebf7203c1f78a529140c182dbbe6b42ae00c02");
    var hash = Convert.FromHexString("ee1511cec71020a9b90443b37b1d5f6e703030f6");
    var rid = Convert.FromHexString("A000000003");
    var index = (byte)149;
    byte[] exp = [0x03];

    // validate ca
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    ms.Write(rid);
    ms.WriteByte(index);
    ms.Write(modulus);
    ms.Write(exp);
    var toHash = ms.ToArray();
    var hashed = Crypto.SHA1(toHash);
    Assert.True(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(hash, hashed));
    
    // test recovery algo
    var recovered = Crypto.PerformRSA(data, exp, modulus);
    Assert.Equal(0x6A, recovered[0]);
    Assert.Equal(0xBC, recovered.Last());
```

Here is the implementation

```
`public static byte[] PerformRSA(byte[] dataBytes, byte[] expBytes, byte[] modBytes)
{
    int inBytesLength = dataBytes.Length;

    if (expBytes[0] >= (byte)0x80)
    {
        // Prepend 0x00 to exponent
        byte[] tmp = new byte[expBytes.Length + 1];
        tmp[0] = (byte)0x00;
        Array.Copy(expBytes, 0, tmp, 1, expBytes.Length);
        expBytes = tmp;
    }

    if (modBytes[0] >= (byte)0x80)
    {
        // Prepend 0x00 to modulus
        byte[] tmp = new byte[modBytes.Length + 1];
        tmp[0] = (byte)0x00;
        Array.Copy(modBytes, 0, tmp, 1, modBytes.Length);
        modBytes = tmp;
    }

    if (dataBytes[0] >= (byte)0x80)
    {
        // Prepend 0x00 to signed data to avoid that the most significant bit is interpreted as the "signed" bit
        byte[] tmp = new byte[dataBytes.Length + 1];
        tmp[0] = (byte)0x00;
        Array.Copy(dataBytes, 0, tmp, 1, dataBytes.Length);
        dataBytes = tmp;
    }

    System.Numerics.BigInteger exp = new(expBytes);
    System.Numerics.BigInteger mod = new(modBytes);
    System.Numerics.BigInteger data = new(dataBytes);

    byte[] result = System.Numerics.BigInteger.ModPow(data, exp, mod).ToByteArray();

    if (result.Length == (inBytesLength + 1) && result[0] == (byte)0x00)
    {
        // Remove 0x00 from beginning of array
        byte[] tmp = new byte[inBytesLength];
        Array.Copy(result, 1, tmp, 0, inBytesLength);
        result = tmp;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I can't figure out why this is failing. The data is from the test in javaemvreader IssuerPublicKeyCertificate.java but my own card data also doesn't pass. Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the process failing?  Is there an error message?

Comment: the unit test fails. Assertion that the first byte is 0x6A and last byte is 0xBC. I tried java and it was same issue. So the question is what other transformation needs to be done to the issuer public key certificate (tag 90) to get the certificate information out. It must start with 0x6A and end with 0xBC to be valid according to the EMV standard book 2.

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked it out. the issue had to do with little endian vs big endian. Below is the working RSA Recovery Function in c#:

```
public static string RecoverSigned(string signedHex, string expHex, string modHex)
{
    var exp = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("00" + expHex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    var mod = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("00" + modHex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    var data = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("00" + signedHex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    var result = System.Numerics.BigInteger.ModPow(data, exp, mod);

    return result.ToString("X");
}
```